# Check condition when Add to car Button is clicked Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In my Prestashop web there are 3 types  of products (In stock, On demand and Coming soon). When a user clicks on Add to cart button in product page, it should shows an alert saying the products cannot be mixed (you cannot buy a product in stock and a product on demand). I use BlockCart module but I cant find the file which I have to edit. Also, I have looked in CartController or ProductController but nothing.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You Can check in `controllers/front/CartController.php` for **processChangeProductInCart** Function.